# Meaning of the verb 'servir' in the Genesis 11

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, usage, verbes

*"Tout le monde se servait d’une même langue et des mêmes mots."* FR

"*Now the whole world had one language and a common speech.*" EN

What is the meaning of the verb 'senvir' in the first sentence? Why not use parlait or avait?

Comment: "Se servir de quelquechose" = "use something" in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Se servir* means to use, so the French sentence translates to:

> Now the whole world was using the same language and the same words.

Using *parler* would have required to change the end of the sentence as while *parler un langage* is fine, *parler des mots* is odd.

Using *avoir* could have work:

> Tout le monde avait la même langue et les mêmes mots

Answer (score 1):

This is not the verb “sentir” (To feel, to smell) but “servir” (to serve, to use)